# Setting Linq to NHibernate ADO Command Timeout

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, command-timeout

How do I increase the timeout in NHibernate Linq To Sql?

Not the Connection Timeout but the ado command timeout.

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession(NHibernateHelper.Databases.CarrierCDR))
  using (session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
  {
   lCdrs = (from verizon in session.Linq<Domain.Verizon>()
             where verizon.Research == true
             && verizon.ReferenceTable == null
             orderby verizon.CallBillingDate descending 
              select verizon).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Will someone please edit the title of this question to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

if you are configuring your NHibernate session with the web.config you can add this to the config:

```
<add key="hibernate.command_timeout" value="0" />
```

Comment: The problem is that this property isn't used for the actual command when Linq query is executed. It always timeouts after ~30 sec.

Answer (score 0):

The only mention of a command timeout parameter in all of fluent nhibernate's source code is in a `FirebirdConfiguration` object.  Which configures the application for the firebird database, which you are probably not using.  I would suggest playing with your configuration objects, and consulting your database's connection string reference.

The `Raw` function in the `PersistenceConfiguration` may allow you to access the properties you are looking for, like `FirebirdConfiguration`, you could add the line `Raw("command_timeout", "444");`, to where your configure nhibernate.